# Express static doesn't load node_modules directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why my website cannot use node_modules directory? This is my server.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8080, 'localhost');
```

I succeed with using public directory but no matter what I write, nothing happens. I tried to add this.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

Still nothing. When I add this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Everything seems work, but then when I add routes to my website, server serves all files to the client and all controllers and this become a problem.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.
That's my project structure:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here? The static directory is where you put all files that are supposed to be **served to the user/client**, not your "internal" app files, those go somewhere else ?

Comment: I just want to load files from node_modules folder, but when I do this, I recieve MIME mistake

Comment: in my public folder, i have index.html and in it I load with script tags libraries which are in node_modules folder

Comment: What path do you use when you're trying to load files from node_modules?

Comment: <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>

Comment: Again, generally what's in `node_modules` is intended for the **server side only**. Everything that is in `/public` is intended for **client side only**.

Comment: Remove two dots before node_modules and node_modules also, just use slash: `/`: `<script src="/systemjs/dist/system.js"`...

Comment: how can i use node_modules in client side.. i need jquery and other libraries there

Comment: Why do you need to have them there, put those files in `/public` where they are supposed to be. Opening up the main `node_modules` folder is not a good thing, that folder, and the root folder, should be completely inaccessible from the clientside

Comment: When I have ten libraries for example where I should put them.. Aren't they have to be in node_modules folder.

Comment: The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js”
  was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Comment: The files under `node_modules` are generally libraries used by your source code.  Usually you _build_ your source code into a `bundle.js` (or similar) and serve that up to the client as a static file.

Comment: I am not heard nothing about bundle.js.. That's my first project

Comment: The files only have to be in `node_modules` if they are actually modules being used by Node on the serverside. If it's just clientside scripts, you put them in `/public`, and there's nothing wrong with having them both places, if you use them both places. You could also use some sort of "system" that builds everything for you, minimizes, bundles etc, but you don't have to.

Comment: Perhaps look at a tutorial on building client-side javascript projects using nodejs tools.

Comment: For example; [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

Comment: But if I don't want to make serious project, is there any way just to make using node_modules folder possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not normally need to access node module in that fashion. If you want to use a module titled `fake-module` you would run `npm i --save fake-module` in your console. This installs it in your node_modules folder but you need not access it using the directory path. Instead you would simply instantiate `const fakeModule = require('fake-module')`, at the top of your express file. That module could conceivably be reached in some alternate way using the directory path, but that's not standard practice and I've never run into a situation where it would be necessary. After instantiating you should be able to use every exported piece of the module using the fakeModule variable.